# If I pass a where clause as a parameter will that prevent SQL Injection?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-injection

I created an Oracle proc where I create a dynamic sql statement based on the parameters supplied to the proc.

I've done some testing and it appears that I can't perform sql injection.

Is there anything additional I should be safe guarding against?

```
SELECT 'UPDATE ' || p_table || ' SET MY_FIELD =  ''' || p_Value || ''' ' || p_Where
            INTO query_string
            FROM DUAL;
```

EDIT:

```
Scenarios that I've tried.
1. WHERE SOME_VAL IN ('AAA','BBB') - This works
2. WHERE SOME_VAL IN ('AAA','BBB') OR SOME_VAL2 = '123' - This works.
3. WHERE SOME_VAL IN ('AAA','BBB'); DROP TABLE TEST_TABLE; - This errors out.
4. WHERE SOME_VAL IN ('AAA','BBB') OR (DELETE FROM TEST_TABLE) - This errors out.
```

Comment: Seem to me you tested it wrong. Looks not safe at all to me. How did you test it?

Comment: See edit for test scenarios.

Comment: Oracle won't allow more then one statement to be executed with a single `execute` statement so you are safe regarding the `drop table` "attack". But you are not protected against e.g. `or 1=1` which would then result in changing **all**  rows in the table. Unrelated, but: you don't need a `select` statement to assign a value, a simple `query_string := 'update ....'||...;` will do just fine

Comment: as @a_horse_with_no_name is saying, thsi won't protect you from `OR` conditions that always evaluate to true, e.g. `OR 1=1` or `OR 1 <> 0` etc.

Comment: Ah yes.  I understand that.  In my proc in the worse case they could only update 1 field (albeit for all records). Since my proc is only set to update MY_FIELD.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how and by whom your procedure is being invoked. Usually you need to worry about SQL injection for something that is open to large number of users in production. And that should not be the case for any database procedure. If your database procedure is accessible by large number of users, then you have potential for malicious use by someone.

In your case, you can mitigate this risk by creating mapping of parameters to hide actual schema object names and some validation.

For example change parameter p_table to table_name as input parameter. Then using case statement map to actual table name. I am giving you example of table name here because you should really restrict who can access which table from db.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc(table_name IN VARCHAR)
  IS
  p_table varchar2(100);
BEGIN

  CASE table_name 
     WHEN 'A' THEN p_table:='db_table_a';
     WHEN 'B' THEN p_table:='db_table_b';
     ELSE RAISE 'Invalid table name parameter';
  END CASE;
  SELECT 'UPDATE ' || p_table || ' SET MY_FIELD =  ''' || p_Value || ''' ' 
         || p_Where
        INTO query_string
        FROM DUAL; 
END;
```

You should do similar mapping and validation for other parameters too.

Comment: I have a web page where I am assembling the where clause in my code.  However I recently came across a need to enter a "custom where statement"  ie. Test scenario #2.  I want to be sure that I'm not opening up pandora's box by allowing this.

Comment: Does your webpage accept where clause as parameter? If so, the validation must be implemented in web page to avoid SQL injection. It is always better to accept not exact value like where clause. But accept an "easy to use" value from user and then translate into a where clause using CASE statement or other means.

Answer (score 1):

SQL injection always opens Pandora's box.

You should always assume a user can break out of a dynamic SQL statement.  With full SQL access you should then assume a user can find a way to escalate privileges and own your database.  (Depending on how paranoid you are, it *might* be safe to assume privilege escalation is impossible as long as your database and schemas are constantly patched and thoroughly hardened.  In practice the vast majority of Oracle databases are *not* sufficiently patched and hardened.)

Below are a few simple examples that should scare you.  And you should also assume that there are many hackers who are more clever than I am and have better attacks.

---

### Sample Schema

First let's create a simple table with some data for a realistic test.

```
drop table test1;

create table test1(my_field varchar2(100), some_val varchar2(100));
insert into test1 values('A', 'AAA');
commit;
```

### Obviously Dangerous Function

Are all of the existing functions safe?

```
create or replace function dangerous_function return number is
    pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
    delete from test1;
    commit;
    return 1;
end;
/
```

If not, what is stopping the user from calling it like this?

```
--Safe static part:
update test1
set my_field = 'b'
--Dangerous dynamic part:
where some_val IN ('AAA')
    and 1 = (select dangerous_function from dual)
```

Luckily creating an autonomous function is unusual and you can probably check the code.  But can you guarantee the application will not create one in the future?

### Custom Function in SQL

Even if there are no objects a clever user can turn your UPDATE into other DML:

```
--Safe static part:
update --+ WITH_PLSQL
test1
set my_field = 'b'
--Dangerous dynamic part:
where some_val IN ('AAA')
    and 1 = (
        with function dangerous_function return number is
            pragma autonomous_transaction;
        begin
            delete from test1;
            commit;
            return 1;
        end;
        select dangerous_function from dual
    );
```

I did cheat a little, the above code only works for me with the `--+ WITH_PLSQL` hint.  Without that hint the code throws the error `ORA-32034: unsupported use of WITH clause`.  But that's only a version limitation that might be lifted in the future.  Or there might be some clever way to work around it, sometimes hints can break out of their part of the query and reference other sections.

### Why Risk It?

Maybe there is a safe way to do it.  But why risk it?  Everybody in the IT world understands SQL injection bugs now.  If you mess up and cause an exploit there will be no sympathy for you.